# Center Tapped Transformer secondary winding direction

Tags: transformer, inverter

For a 12-0-12 Step Down Center Tapped Transformer, what should be the direction of the winding on secondary coils (One End - CT, CT - Other End)? Should they be in opposite direction? If it is 'same direction' would it have any relation with primary windings direction?
Note: the transformer will be used in reverse to step up voltage in a DC-AC Square Wave inverter where the CT will always receive +ve DC voltage.

Also, is there any change required in terms of winding direction, if used in a Full Bridge inverter?

Comment: A *reverse* Step Down is called Step Up, so please simplify your description. The transformer does not care about transforming the voltage up or down ;-) What does the 12-0-12 mean?

Comment: @auoa "12-0-12" means a 24 V winding with a provided centertap.

Comment: A 12-0-12 winding is just continuous. If you imagine winding a single 24 V secondary, but right in the middle of it were to scrape bare a very short segment and solder a "centertap" to that bare spot, you'd roughly have it. What I do is bring out about an inch or two of wire at the half-way point, kink and fold it back to the core, and continue winding in exactly the same direction as before. Later, I clean the kinked end and use it as the centertap.

Comment: The  orientation of secondary winding for isolated AC does not matter, but impedance ratio does matter. 1:10 voltage ratio raises source impedance 1:100, so source must be very low to start with. What I do is fold a magnet wire in two then wind the pair if you want matched outputs to avoid DC imbalance, then reverse one pair connections to create the center tap.

Comment: Allow 10% load loss and 70% for peak to RMS in your turns ratio

Comment: The term "CT" is normally reserved for "current transformer" and definitely not "centre tapped". Please amend to avoid confusion and attract more answers (none at present).

Comment: Andy, it was my bad. done.

Comment: @tony when you fold the wire and wind, by default the turns directions from 2  edges to the center become reverse. Do you mean, reverse direction is correct? Little confused now, since it contradicts with jonk 's response. I am assuming after folding the wires, you wind the coil and then split/cut from fold's center and join one of the splitted end with one of the edges to actually form the center tap. This way, still the winding direction from edge to Ct and CT to edge remains in same direction.

Comment: I meant wind in pairs gives best matching, but you'll get 0 inductance this way, so folded end must be cut and one pc. connected to other wire end becomes C Tap. This is called "Bifilar Method"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If it is 'same direction' would it have any relation with primary
>   windings direction?

The two windings are wound in the same direction just like this little ferrite wound component: -

[image]

If the centre-tap wasn't there the orange and red would be one continuous winding in the same direction.

The direction that both have in reference to the primary winding is of no-importance for AC power transformers but, in other applications like transformer fed loudspeaker arrays it would make a massive difference at bass frequencies if one transformer had the opposite phase to another.

> Also, is there any change required in terms of winding direction, if
>   used in a Full Bridge inverter?

No.

Comment: That makes it clear to me. Yhanks for the response with an easy to understand image.